# Can Facebook app developers count the number of comments people make to posts made by those facebook apps on users' newsfeed

Tags: facebook

For instance, if you have seen the Nike running app it posts on the users stream every time they finish a run. In many occasions these posts receive comments or likes from that users friends. Does nike as the developer have access to the number of comments and likes that are generated to posts made by their application? And on that subject, do they have access to the number of impressions these posts receive?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

definitivly not the number of impressions, that's not given out by facebook. But the facebook graph api gives you access to the number of comments and number of likes of a post, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.

[Update] For a post made by the app through the graph api, you will receive the postid, which in turn should allow you to read the information you've asked for. BUT you're still required to have read_stream permission to read all the necessary information.

Got me curious, and i just tested: you can post with an application to the users wall and won't be able to read this post back from the users wall. If you have the correct permissions, it's however pretty easy. Just save the post_id or query it.

Finally, to answer your question: if the nike apps asks for read_stream permission , it will be able to read all information. Otherwise it's a fire-and-forget setting

Comment: Thanks LordT; sorry for my ignorance. Another question: it looks like for publicly available posts you could get a lot of data about comments and likes but will an app be able to get a list of ids for the posts that were made through it? thanks so much.